# Multi-platform program to report computer/device usage times

Tags: android, linux, ios, monitoring

We have 3 subnetworks with a bunch of devices, all running on either Debian, Android, or iOS. We need a tool to:

- Collect the time of day those devices are in use and
- Report them to a central server (or the server fetches the logs)
- Optional: some nice graphs

I'm pretty sure there are some classic sysadmin tools for this purpose, but I wasn't able to find them.

Google mostly returns networking monitoring tools, but we really do need a software, that reads the login/logout times.

Any ideas?